# JArray. How process Jarray if index may change?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need process JSON file that may contain different number of items in JSON array. Currently I'm using such code:

```
var obj = JArray.Parse(File.ReadAllText(url));
dfd = (from a in obj
       where
           a["PriceItems"][0]["CityFromID"].Value<string>() == cityfromcode &&
           a["PriceItems"][0]["CityToID"].Value<string>() == citytocode &&
           a["PriceItems"][0]["AirlineCode"].Value<string>() == airlinecode
       select new PricesViewModel.DepartureFlightsData
       {
           DepartureCity = a["PriceItems"][0]["CityFromName"].Value<string>(),
           DepartureAirport = a["PriceItems"][0]["AirportFromCode"].Value<string>(),
           DepartureDate = depDate,
           DepartureTime = a["PriceItems"][0]["DepartureTime"].Value<string>(),
           DepartureAirline = a["PriceItems"][0]["AirlineCode"].Value<string>(),
           DepartureFlight = a["PriceItems"][0]["FlightNumber"].Value<string>(),
           DepartureFlightId = a["PriceItems"][0]["FlightID"].Value<string>(),
           Price = a["PriceItems"][0]["Price"].Value<int>(),
           Currency = a["PriceItems"][0]["Currency"].Value<string>()
       }).FirstOrDefault();
```

But this code will be valid only for the items at specific index, how should I change this code to be able process items on some specific position, different from [0]?

JSON may change from this:

```
[
  {
    "PriceItems": [
      {
        "FlightID": "567",
        "FlightNumber": "001",
        "CityFromID": "1",
        "CityFromCode": "MOW",
        "CityToID": "539",
        "CityToCode": "",
        "AirportFromCode": "DME",
        "AirportFromName": null,
        "AirportToCode": "VRN",
        "AirportToName": null,
        "DepartureDate": "20150318",
        "DepartureTime": "10:00",
        "ArrivalDate": "20150318",
        "ArrivalTime": "12:00",
        "Price": 300,
        "Currency": "€",
        "AirServiceID": "89",
        "AirCraft": "aerobus A-310",
        "AirlineName": "Сан Экспресс",
        "AirlineCode": "00",
        "PackageID": "232",
        "CityFromName": "Москва",
        "CityToName": "ВАРНА"
      },
      {
        "FlightID": "568",
        "FlightNumber": "002",
        "CityFromID": "539",
        "CityFromCode": null,
        "CityToID": "1",
        "CityToCode": null,
        "AirportFromCode": "VRN",
        "AirportFromName": null,
        "AirportToCode": "DME",
        "AirportToName": null,
        "DepartureDate": "20150319",
        "DepartureTime": "12:00",
        "ArrivalDate": "20150319",
        "ArrivalTime": "14:00",
        "Price": 300,
        "Currency": "€",
        "AirServiceID": "89",
        "AirCraft": "aerobus A-310",
        "AirlineName": "Сан Экспресс",
        "AirlineCode": "00",
        "PackageID": "232",
        "CityFromName": "ВАРНА",
        "CityToName": "Москва"
      }
    ],
    "VariantItems": [
      {
        "FlightID": "567",
        "FlightBackID": "568"
      }
    ],
    "Error": null
  },
  {
    "PriceItems": [
      {
        "FlightID": "569",
        "FlightNumber": "546",
        "CityFromID": "1",
        "CityFromCode": "MOW",
        "CityToID": "559",
        "CityToCode": "",
        "AirportFromCode": "DME",
        "AirportFromName": null,
        "AirportToCode": "SFA",
        "AirportToName": null,
        "DepartureDate": "20150318",
        "DepartureTime": "08:00",
        "ArrivalDate": "20150318",
        "ArrivalTime": "10:00",
        "Price": 200,
        "Currency": "€",
        "AirServiceID": "89",
        "AirCraft": "Boeing",
        "AirlineName": "BRITISH  AIRWAYS",
        "AirlineCode": "BA",
        "PackageID": "232",
        "CityFromName": "Москва",
        "CityToName": "СОФИЯ"
      },
      {
        "FlightID": "571",
        "FlightNumber": "547",
        "CityFromID": "559",
        "CityFromCode": null,
        "CityToID": "1",
        "CityToCode": null,
        "AirportFromCode": "SFA",
        "AirportFromName": null,
        "AirportToCode": "DME",
        "AirportToName": null,
        "DepartureDate": "20150319",
        "DepartureTime": "18:00",
        "ArrivalDate": "20150319",
        "ArrivalTime": "20:00",
        "Price": 185,
        "Currency": "€",
        "AirServiceID": "89",
        "AirCraft": "Boeing",
        "AirlineName": "BRITISH  AIRWAYS",
        "AirlineCode": "BA",
        "PackageID": "232",
        "CityFromName": "СОФИЯ",
        "CityToName": "Москва"
      }
    ],
    "VariantItems": [
      {
        "FlightID": "569",
        "FlightBackID": "571"
      }
    ],
    "Error": null
  }
]
```

to that one:

```
[
  {
    "PriceItems": [
      {
        "FlightID": "565",
        "FlightNumber": "731",
        "CityFromID": "1",
        "CityFromCode": "MOW",
        "CityToID": "19",
        "CityToCode": "BCN",
        "AirportFromCode": "DME",
        "AirportFromName": null,
        "AirportToCode": "BCN",
        "AirportToName": null,
        "DepartureDate": "20150318",
        "DepartureTime": "17:00",
        "ArrivalDate": "20150318",
        "ArrivalTime": "21:00",
        "Price": 350,
        "Currency": "€",
        "AirServiceID": "89",
        "AirCraft": "Boeing",
        "AirlineName": "TRANSAERO",
        "AirlineCode": "UN",
        "PackageID": "232",
        "CityFromName": "Москва",
        "CityToName": "Барселона"
      },
      {
        "FlightID": "563",
        "FlightNumber": "2639",
        "CityFromID": "1",
        "CityFromCode": "MOW",
        "CityToID": "19",
        "CityToCode": "BCN",
        "AirportFromCode": "SVO",
        "AirportFromName": null,
        "AirportToCode": "BCN",
        "AirportToName": null,
        "DepartureDate": "20150318",
        "DepartureTime": "11:50",
        "ArrivalDate": "20150318",
        "ArrivalTime": "19:15",
        "Price": 350,
        "Currency": "€",
        "AirServiceID": "89",
        "AirCraft": "Boeing",
        "AirlineName": "Aeroflot-Russian International AirLines",
        "AirlineCode": "SU",
        "PackageID": "232",
        "CityFromName": "Москва",
        "CityToName": "Барселона"
      },
      {
        "FlightID": "566",
        "FlightNumber": "732",
        "CityFromID": "19",
        "CityFromCode": null,
        "CityToID": "1",
        "CityToCode": null,
        "AirportFromCode": "BCN",
        "AirportFromName": null,
        "AirportToCode": "DME",
        "AirportToName": null,
        "DepartureDate": "20150319",
        "DepartureTime": "07:00",
        "ArrivalDate": "20150319",
        "ArrivalTime": "11:00",
        "Price": 350,
        "Currency": "€",
        "AirServiceID": "89",
        "AirCraft": "Boeing",
        "AirlineName": "TRANSAERO",
        "AirlineCode": "UN",
        "PackageID": "232",
        "CityFromName": "Барселона",
        "CityToName": "Москва"
      },
      {
        "FlightID": "564",
        "FlightNumber": "2640",
        "CityFromID": "19",
        "CityFromCode": null,
        "CityToID": "1",
        "CityToCode": null,
        "AirportFromCode": "BCN",
        "AirportFromName": null,
        "AirportToCode": "SVO",
        "AirportToName": null,
        "DepartureDate": "20150319",
        "DepartureTime": "11:50",
        "ArrivalDate": "20150319",
        "ArrivalTime": "14:50",
        "Price": 350,
        "Currency": "€",
        "AirServiceID": "89",
        "AirCraft": "Boeing",
        "AirlineName": "Aeroflot-Russian International AirLines",
        "AirlineCode": "SU",
        "PackageID": "232",
        "CityFromName": "Барселона",
        "CityToName": "Москва"
      }
    ],
    "VariantItems": [
      {
        "FlightID": "563",
        "FlightBackID": "566"
      },
      {
        "FlightID": "565",
        "FlightBackID": "566"
      },
      {
        "FlightID": "563",
        "FlightBackID": "564"
      },
      {
        "FlightID": "565",
        "FlightBackID": "564"
      }
    ],
    "Error": null
  }
]
```

Comment: @stefankmitph, no, this will not work. I may do not know postion, it may be 0 or 1 or 10.

Comment: can you post the json string?

Comment: May I suggest a simpler answer that does not use the `JArray` at all (still uses json.NET, just a bit different pattern)?

Comment: As you can see from the JSON string I posted, PriceItems may have 2 or 4 or some other number of children items.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal, if your solution may process different number of children items, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, you'd like receive first of all "PriceItems" objects.
You can use [SelectMany() LINQ extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534336%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That method will do exactly what you want:

```
var obj = JArray.Parse(File.ReadAllText(url));
dfd = obj.SelectMany(x => x["PriceItems"])
   .Select(a => new PricesViewModel.DepartureFlightsData {
       DepartureCity = a["CityFromName"].Value<string>(),
       DepartureAirport = a["AirportFromCode"].Value<string>(),
       DepartureDate = depDate,
       DepartureTime = a["DepartureTime"].Value<string>(),
       DepartureAirline = a["AirlineCode"].Value<string>(),
       DepartureFlight = a["FlightNumber"].Value<string>(),
       DepartureFlightId = a["FlightID"].Value<string>(),
       Price = a["Price"].Value<int>(),
       Currency = a["Currency"].Value<string>()
   }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler alternative.

```
public class VarientItemsPlaceHolder
{
     public string FlightID;
     public string FlightBackID;
}

public class OuterJsonObject
{
      public List<PricesViewModel.DepartureFlightsData> PriceItems;
      public List<VarientItemsPlaceHolder> VarientItems;
      public strint Error;
}

// deserialize the whole thing first
List<OuterJsonObject> everything = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OuterJsonObject>(File.ReadAllText(url));

// flatten the Lists of PricesViewModel.DepartureFlightsData into one master List<PricesViewModel.DepartureFlightsData>   
List<PricesViewModel.DepartureFlightsData> allFlights = everything.SelectMany(x => x.PricedItems).ToList();


// filter the master list using cityfromcode, citytocode, airlinecode
List<PricesViewModel.DepartureFlightsData> filteredFlights = allFlights.Where(x => x.CityFromID == cityfromcode && x.CityToID == citytocode && x.AirlineCode == airlinecode).ToList();
```

Note that you do not have to break this out as much as I have. The code could be condensed by composing some of these LINQ queries, I just chose to do it step by step because it makes data processing more clear imo.

As someone else pointed out, the key is to use the `SelectMany` method to aggregate all of the `PricedItems` from each object containing that list. I personally much prefer to use static types. You're using a `JArray` as an intermediary, before converting to your Model type, that could be continued and you probably already have the types I've defined here in your models somewhere so don't use my class definitions, I just put them there to be clear about how it all works. The json is equivalent to my `OuterJsonObject` type, after I've deserialized into that I'm just LINQ query or two away from having the filtered list you want.